# Unable to get drawer navigation home button to work

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to put together a tab navigator, drawer navigator, and stack navigator through react-native expo. When I open the Drawer Navigator and click About, it will take me to the about page. But, when I try to go back to Home through Drawer Navigator, it does not take me back to home page. Any idea where my mistake is?

Below is my App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from "react-native";

//React Navigation Libraries
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation-drawer";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-tabs";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs";


//Assets
import colors from "./assets/colors";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import CustomDrawerComponent from "./screens/DrawerNavigation/CustomDrawerComponent";

//Screen Imports
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import AboutScreen from "./screens/AboutScreen";
import LoadingScreen from "./screens/AppSwitchNavigator/LoadingScreen"
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <AppContainer />
    );
  }
}


const HomeTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    HomeScreen: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Home",
        tabBarIcon: () => (
          <Ionicons name="ios-apps" size={24} color={colors.logoColor} />
        )
      }
    },

    AboutScreen: {
      screen: AboutScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "About",
        tabBarIcon: () => (
          <Ionicons name="ios-stats" size={24} color={colors.logoColor} />
        )
      }
    }
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      style: {
        backgroundColor: colors.bgMain,
        paddingTop: 10
      },
      activeTintColor: colors.bgPrimary,
      inactiveTintColor: colors.bgTextInput
    }
  }
);

const HomeStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    HomeTabNavigator: {
      screen: HomeTabNavigator,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
          headerLeft: () => (
            <Ionicons
              name="ios-menu"
              size={30}
              color={colors.logoColor}
              onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
              style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
            />
          )
        };
      }
    },
    HomeScreen: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
    }
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: colors.bgMain
      },
      headerTitle: "Example",
      headerBackTitle: "Back",
      headerTintColor: colors.txtWhite
    }
  }
);

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    HomeStackNavigator: {
      screen: HomeStackNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Home",

        drawerIcon: () => (
          <Ionicons name="ios-home" size={24} color={colors.logoColor} />
        )
      }
    },
    AboutScreen: {
      screen: AboutScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Settings",
        drawerIcon: () => (
          <Ionicons name="ios-settings" size={24} color={colors.logoColor} />
        )
      }
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'HomeStackNavigator',
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerComponent,
    drawerBackgroundColor: colors.bgMain,
    contentOptions: {
      labelStyle: {
        color: colors.bgPrimary
      },
      activeBackgroundColor: colors.bgMain
    }
  }
);

const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  LoadingScreen,
  AppDrawerNavigator
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator);
export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: colors.bgMain,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

Comment: Can u share it on snack?

Comment: I can't seem to get the snack dependencies to work. It gives me error with importing react-navigation-tabs. Feel free to try: https://snack.expo.io/@singamnv/adequate-fudge

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I switched to React Navigation 5 and this simplified my life. The reworked code is below for App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from "react-native";

//React Navigation Libraries

import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer"


//Assets
import colors from "./assets/colors";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import CustomDrawerComponent from "./screens/DrawerNavigation/CustomDrawerComponent";
import Header from "./screens/DrawerNavigation/Header";

//Screen Imports
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import AboutScreen from "./screens/AboutScreen";



const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();
const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator();
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();
const AboutStack = createStackNavigator();

const HomeStackScreen = () => (
  <HomeStack.Navigator>
    <HomeStack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen}/>
  </HomeStack.Navigator>
)

const AboutStackScreen = () => (
  <AboutStack.Navigator>
    <AboutStack.Screen name="AboutScreen" component={AboutScreen} />
  </AboutStack.Navigator>
);

const TabsScreen = () => (
  <Tabs.Navigator>
    <Tabs.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeStackScreen} />
    <Tabs.Screen name="AboutScreen" component={AboutStackScreen} />
  </Tabs.Navigator>
);

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default () => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={TabsScreen} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="About" component={AboutStackScreen} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
    {/* <AuthStack.Navigator>
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="HomeScreen"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{ title: "Home Screen" }}
      />
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="AboutScreen"
        component={AboutScreen}
        options={{ title: "About Screen" }}
      />
    </AuthStack.Navigator> */}
  </NavigationContainer>
);
```